# Actionscript delay inside function

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, wait

I created a button in Adobe Animate which should, if you press him be exchanged with another button in a different color, after 1 second you should be forwarded to the previous scene.

My Code:

```
button_answer_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToPreviousScene);
function fl_ClickToGoToPreviousScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    button_answer_2.visible = false;
    button_answer_2_red.visible = true;


        setTimeout(myDelayedFunction,3000);
        function myDelayedFunction(){
                MovieClip(this.root).prevScene();
            }
}
```

sadly the myDelayedFunction doesn't work because it is inside another fuction, I can't see analternative way. Could anyone help me? (I am not the best programmer so keep it simple if possible)

Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Then why not simply move the function out of the other one. There was never a reason to nest them to begin with.

```
button_answer_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToPreviousScene);
function fl_ClickToGoToPreviousScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    button_answer_2.visible = false;
    button_answer_2_red.visible = true;

    setTimeout(myDelayedFunction,3000);
}

function myDelayedFunction():void
{
    MovieClip(this.root).prevScene();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inline function and test again, I can not test it now:

```
setTimeout(function(){ MovieClip(this.root).prevScene(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: That's a function expression, which causes `this` to be the global object. That's not part of the display list hierarchy and doesn't have a `root` property.